# AngularJS - targeting elements inside an ng-repeat loop on $(document).ready

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Being new to AngularJS, I'm looking for a way to target elements inside an `ng-repeat` loop after `$(document).ready` is fired. They don't seem to be ready at the time however. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why are you using $(document).ready? If you are using angular you should create a directive to what you want to do.

Comment: This thread corroborates Renal's suggestion to use a directive and also mentions the $viewContentLoaded event as a (quick) alternative: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/angular/ywXw9oNFNbI/discussion

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions, I'm now looking more into using directives.

Comment: `ng-repeat` probably will not have cloned itself on `$(document).ready`. As others have mentioned, you probably want to write a directive, but it would help if you provided more context. What are you trying to do to the elements inside `ng-repeat`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [blog post](http://www.aleaiactaest.ch/angular-js-and-dom-readyness-for-jquery/) discusses listening to the `$viewContentLoaded` event in your controller to call your function instead of using `$(document).ready`:

```
function stuffController($scope) {
    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', readyFunction);
}
```

Comment: In case i want to call the angular js function based on a condition in document.ready, how will i get it?

Comment: @Wilson readyFunction in this example can be an function in the controller or on the scope. Does that help? If not, what type of condition in document.ready are you looking for?