# how to use select2 4.0 with angularjs, when to init it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-select2-4

I want to bind my ajax loaded data with select2 option, but where should I put my init code? I use select2 4.0, so there is no thing like ui-select, I want to try to use the select2 4.0 directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it on ready function.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    //call your init function or place init code here
});
```

**UPDATE**:
For angularjs refer
[Call angular function on document ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838205/call-angular-function-on-document-ready)

Comment: sorry, I want to init in my controller, not the document ready function, because I load my document when I need it. So this way doesn't work as I tried. can you give me an example? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create an angular directive or component and write your select2 initialization and rest of the select2 related code over there.

**Edit:** You can call the API endpoint in your service and define a variable in the controller then bind the data in a variable so that your view can access it. Once you get the data in a variable you can pass this variable to you directive/component.
Also if you want to make an API call once the user types something you can use data property of select2 https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax. and this entire selct2 logic can reside in your directive/component.

Creating directive/component will make your jquery code in the angular environment

and then use the directive/component in your view.