# AngularJS - Call jquery after load

Tags: jquery, slider, angularjs

I have an image slider on my page:
That is my call:

```
<div id="slider">
    <ul class="bjqs">
        <li ng-repeat="image in dealer.images"><img src="{{image}}" alt="{{image}}" /></li>   
    </ul>
</div>
```

Somehow the slider doesn't work. I think I have to load the jQuery init after the images are loaded.
This is the call for the slider:

```
$('#slider').bjqs({
            height      : 420,
            width       : 130,
            responsive  : true
          });
```

How can I call this function after the images are loaded?

Comment: Maybe [ngSrc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSrc) or [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454383/angularjs-targeting-elements-inside-an-ng-repeat-loop-on-document-ready) can help?

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that's the problem than you can use [Nick Craver's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3877079/603127)

```
$(".bjqs img").one('load', function() {
   $('#slider').bjqs({
       height      : 420,
       width       : 130,
       responsive  : true
   });  
}).each(function() {
   if(this.complete) $(this).load();
});
```

Comment: Nope, this wasn't the solution. The slider still wants to load the angular scope : slider/%7B%7Bimage%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @Marek123, I think there is an error on image link, did you encode it?